# Using a DrawerLayout along with a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, drawerlayout

I'm trying to write an android app with a listview of a few different items and also a drawerlayout that you can drag from the left side of the screen. Here's what i mean....

This is what the main screen looks like:
[image]

And here's what the drawer menu thing looks like:
[image]

The problem i'm having is that when I open the side drawer menu thing and tap an option it doesn't work and the menu just closes. However i'm able to interact with the main listview page. Here's what my code looks like:

```
String[] homeArray = { "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test" };

private ListView homeListView;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;



private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mDrawerTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Menu);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles));
```

And the activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#111"
    />
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".ListActivity" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/homeListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have a feeling the problem is in the xml but i'm not sure.

Comment: You will have to post the full code of your draweractivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post the full code of your Activity that holds the NavigationDrawer.

Furthermore, **I would strongly recommend (and so would Google) that you use Fragments for the individual NavigationDrawer sections** ("Settings", "Submit Bug" and "Help" in your case).

> **Do not put all the layout components into the layout file of your Activity.**

The layout therefore should look like the following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**The FrameLayout content_frame is where your Fragment that holds the ListView will go into.**
Simply create a custom Fragment (or use a ListFragment) that contains the ListView you displayed in your picture and insert it into the "content_frame".

Use this to replace Fragments inside the content frame: (when you switch your section)

```
/** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
    Fragment fragment = new YourListFragment(); // this fragment contains the list with all the "test" items

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                   .commit();

    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

An Example of how your Fragment could look like: **YourListFragment.java**
The layout file "list_fragment.xml" simply contains whatever layout components you want. For example a ListView. Initialize an populate the ListView inside the Fragments onCreateView() method.

```
public class YourListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

All taken from Googles example on how to create a NavigationDrawer:

> http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! One question though... should i import android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: That depends whereelse you want to use your Fragment. As for this example, it is save to use standard "android.app.Fragment" and not the support library.